# object I am trying to take the mean of is not found

Tags: r, dataset, mean

All I need to do for this simple assignment, which I have been able to do with no problem before, is take the mean of a column from a `.csv` dataset uploaded to R.

Here is the code I have:

```
library(readr)
X1888B_PSet03_Dataset1 <-read_csv("Downloads/188B_PSet03_Dataset1.csv")
View(X188B_PSet03_Dataset1)
mean(FillerAcc)
```

and this is where I get the error message

> object 'FillerAcc' not found

Meanwhile, there is literally a column table in my data called `FillerAcc`.

Comment: You spelled X188B_PSet03_Dataset1 and X1888B_PSet03_Dataset1 two different ways, and column names are not R objects. I think you need to find a good tutorial and follow along commented code examples.

Comment: What was the output of View?

Answer (score 0):

Call your column this way.

```
mean(X1888B_PSet03_Dataset1$FillerAcc)
```

Comment: Okay awesome, that worked for me. I have no idea what I am doing wrong on this assignment because in the past I could have swore my code was just simply mean(variablename) I actually am not even in an R class and my experience is in C++, but this class I am assumes that I know this much of R!

Comment: You can use the variable name like that if you type this command: attach(yourDataFrame). However it is not a best practice and I do not advise you to do that.